# How to create a patch in Git since last commit?

Tags: git, push, format-patch

What command can I use to create a single patch file containing commits since last push?

Thanks,
Navneet

Comment: Have you tried to search? If you have, what google search request didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To generate individual patches for the `topic` branch, for all the unpushed commits,

```
git fetch
git format-patch origin/topic..topic
```

The generated patches can be applied with `git apply`.

To generate one summary patch instead of individual patches, you can just save the output of `git diff`,

```
git fetch
git diff origin/topic..topic > topic.patch
```